# HTML5 File Upload chunk/slice cause high CPU usage

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, html5-filesystem

So, I'm implementing File Uploader for large file with HTML5. I'm using the new slice/chunk to slice the file into smaller chunk with the purpose of pause/resume for later implementation.
However, everytime I try uploading (it works) but it takes a lot of memory and CPU usage(it could go up to 100% cpu usage). I try different size of chunk file, but no help.

Anyone know what is wrong? and how to fix it? The app supposedly able to support up to 4GB/files, and of course multiple file Thus probably could go to 20GB etc.

note: please don't include java or flash for the solution. Because I have the java version already. I'm just trying to rewrite this with HTML5. Below is the code

```
        function sendRequest() {       
            var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');   

            for(var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++) {      
                var blob = file.files[i];         
                var originalFileName = blob.name;
                var filePart = 0

                const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB chunk sizes.
                const SIZE = blob.size;

                var start = 0;
                var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;

                totalChunks = Math.ceil(SIZE / BYTES_PER_CHUNK);

                while( start < SIZE ) {                    
                    if (blob.webkitSlice) {
                        //for Google Chrome
                        var chunk = blob.webkitSlice(start, end); 
                    } else if (blob.mozSlice) {
                        //for Mozilla Firefox
                        var chunk = blob.mozSlice(start, end);
                        //pausecomp(5000);
                    }       

                    uploadFile(chunk, originalFileName, filePart, totalChunks, i);
                    filePart++;
                    start = end;
                    end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
                }
            }                
        }


        function uploadFile(blobFile, fileName, filePart, totalChunks, divBarsSelector) {
            if(filePart == 0) {
                bars = document.querySelector('#bars' + divBarsSelector);  
            }

            var progress = document.createElement('progress');
            progress.min = 0;
            progress.max = 100;
            progress.value = 0;
            bars.appendChild(progress);   

            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                
            xhr.open("POST", "upload.php"+"?"+"file="+fileName + filePart, true);

            xhr.onload = function(e) {
                //make sure if finish progress bar at 100%
                progress.value = 100;

                //counter if everything is done using stack(pop) / queue(shift)????
                uploaders.shift();

                if (!uploaders.length) {
                    bars.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                    bars.appendChild(document.createTextNode('DONE :)'));
                    //mergeFile(fileName, totalChunks);
                }                  
            };

            // Listen to the upload progress for each upload.   
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {;
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    progress.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                }
            };                 

            uploaders.push(xhr);
            xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Comment: Currently, the slicing loop starts uploads for each block without waiting for prior block to finish. Your slicing loop should wait until the uploader has finished with the current block before starting the upload for the next block.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, I am using websockets and only sending more chunks after a chunk was received but still I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @DanD. so you mean right now the http request directly got send to the server after slice, and I should just send each request sequentially instead of paralelly? Do you have example code or something? Because I'm not sure how to do it. Thank you

Comment: @Harts if you we're using websockets you could have events triggered for when the chunk arrives at the server and it's done processing, in the case of php I'm not sure, you could use EventSource (server sent events) to do the same or you could use setTimeout to delay sending the chunk

Comment: @andrei on your previous comment, "but still I'm doing something  wrong" what does that mean?

Comment: Means that even if I wait for the server to send me an event that requests more chunks the script still eats away at the CPU (and memory too). I wrote a script to test the blob.slice() and it's very fast so the problem is elsewhere . I have a github repo you can see my code https://github.com/piatra/resumableUploads

Comment: Completely rewrote the whole thing today, using only formidable as the only framework to handle the post data and turns out there is a problem sending chunks with XHR2 and FormData() they never reach the nodejs server. Trying to figure this new issue out.. made a gist https://gist.github.com/3003691

Comment: @andrei actually, I just try a simple upload form (no html 5) and upload 2gb file, it still causes high cpu usage. any idea what is wrong? note that I change the php.ini to allow upload 2gb file.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this problem we need to upload files using webworkers, by using webworkers we can reduce the cpu usage.

you can test the difference of with and without webworkers in chrome using chrome taskmanager.